In React, how do I combine two slightly offset videos to create a 3D video (stereoscopic 3D)?
I have two videos recorded simultaneously with a slightly horizontal offset, that are meant to be used together to form a 3D video to be watched with 3D glasses (not the red/blue kind). Is this possible to achieve in React + TypeScript?
I've heard it's possible to do so in Three.js and WebGL, which are both tools I'm open to explore, but I'm wondering if it's something as simple as putting side by side or overlaying the videos with canvas manipulation? What's the best/recommended way to do it?
EDIT: after more research I realised that I need a 3D display in order to achieve this, and it's definitely not as simple as overlaying the two videos. More research is needed to figure out how to make them 3D ready, so that will be my new question. But if anyone has had experience working with something similar, let me know if you have any advice or recommendations.

I have never done such an implementation and if I understand you correctly and what you want to achieve, you can try using StereoCamera.
StereoCamera
More info about setttings and calibration you can find in this article.
Official example reconstructed with videos CodeSandbox
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { StereoEffect } from 'three/examples/jsm/effects/StereoEffect.js'

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null)
  const videoRefs = useRef<HTMLVideoElement[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!containerRef.current) return

    let camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera
    let scene: THREE.Scene
    let renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer
    let effect: StereoEffect

    function init() {
      camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000)
      camera.position.z = 2000

      scene = new THREE.Scene()
      scene.background = new THREE.Color(0x333333)

      const video1 = document.createElement('video')
      video1.src = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/video/2021/11/30/99350-653447896_tiny.mp4' // Replace with your video path
      video1.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
      video1.loop = true
      video1.muted = true
      video1.setAttribute('playsinline', '')
      video1.oncanplay = () => video1.play()
      videoRefs.current.push(video1)

      const video2 = document.createElement('video')
      video2.src = 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/video/2021/11/30/99350-653447896_tiny.mp4' // Replace with your video path
      video2.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
      video2.loop = true
      video2.muted = true
      video2.setAttribute('playsinline', '')
      video2.oncanplay = () => video2.play()
      videoRefs.current.push(video2)

      const texture1 = new THREE.VideoTexture(video1)
      const texture2 = new THREE.VideoTexture(video2)

      const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(800, 450)
      const planeMaterial1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture1 })
      const planeMaterial2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: texture2 })

      const videoPlane1 = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial1)
      const videoPlane2 = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial2)

      videoPlane1.position.set(-600, 0, 0)
      videoPlane2.position.set(600, 0, 0)

      scene.add(videoPlane1)
      scene.add(videoPlane2)

      renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()

      if (!containerRef.current) return
      renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
      containerRef.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

      effect = new StereoEffect(renderer)
      effect.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)

      animate()
    }

    function animate() {
      camera.lookAt(scene.position)
      effect.render(scene, camera)
      requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    }

    init()

    return () => {
      if (renderer) {
        renderer.dispose()
      }
    }
  }, [])

  return <div ref={containerRef} />
}

export default App

